# фукнция mailer php не работает

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<?php
 

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require  'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php'
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
use phpmailer\phpmailer;
use phpmailer\Exception;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$name = 'Name to be displayed!';
$message = 'Never Give Up!';
$subject = 'Test mail!';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'myhost';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myname';
$mail->Password = 'my password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->addReplyTo($to, $name);
$mail->setFrom($to, $name);
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHtml($message);
$mail->send();
?>
```

где можно посмотреть ошибки ?Сайт просто падает с надписью ... не может отобразить ваш запрос

Answer (score 0):

В третьей строчке забыли в конец добавить `;`